# Birthday webpart - SP Online (using AAD as datasource)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, power-automate, azure-active-directory

I'm after a SharePoint Online  birthday webpart that uses Azure AD as the datasource.
My other option is to get the data synced into a SharePoint list and from there I know what to do.
I think I should be able to use Power Automate ( with no premium connector)
I also noticed there is no birthday property field in the Azure AD .
How can I add this?

Thanks in Advance